# UWSGI can't change log file path

Tags: debian, uwsgi

I have a Debian 7 + uwsgi 1.2.3-debian 
I want to change UWSGI log file path, I tried

```
[uwsgi]
   plugins = python27
   chdir = /home/example.com/apps/
   pythonpath = /home/example.com/apps/
   env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
   module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
   touch-reload = /home/example.com/README.md
   logto  = /home/example.com/logs/uwsgi.logto.log;
   daemonize  = /home/example.com/logs/uwsgi.daemonize.log;
   logdate = true
   max-requests = 5000
   buffer-size = 32768
```

But `/home/example.com/logs/` is empty. Log file is still in `/var/log/uwsgi/app/example.com.log`

In Ubuntu 13.04 I don't have this problem, what can I do?

Comment: I don't know how to fix your problem but please, please, please do not use uwsgi 1.2.3 it is **buggy**. See the warning on [this Django page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/). The warning is not mere theory. I've spent hours one day tracking a problem that was due to this bug.

Comment: update to version 2.0.3 from pip dosn't help

Answer (score 1):

Might be too late, but debian package (2.0.7 at least) has a **/usr/share/uwsgi/init/specific_daemon** file where the *--daemonize* is hardcoded. You can change it there, or just remove that line and set on **/usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini** or **/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/appname.ini**.

Comment: Is there any cleaner way to just override it from app's ini? I don't want to touch "/usr/share/uwsgi/init/specific_daemon". Thanks

Comment: Actually, that is the place where it should be done, because is the uwsgi "common" configuration, and daemonize and logto affect to all the applications (Although if you run just one app, you could use the apps-enabled location.

But, in any case, change default logging with debian seems quite uncomfortable. I've tried to use both local file and rsyslog simultaneously (in the config file under apps-enabled), ending in absence of log into local file.